# Open IE From Command Line, Wait X Seconds, Then Close IE

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've managed to open IE but the next scheduled task won't run until IE is closed. Is there a way to say

```
Open IE with these parameters
Wait X Seconds
Close IE

Open IE with these different parameters
Wait X Seconds
Close IE
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're just trying to automatically send web requests to various URLs, IE is probably the wrong tool to use. If that's not what you're trying to do, could you elaborate on what it is that you are trying to achieve - IE still might not be the right tool for the job.

Comment: Have added an answer - it can be any browser

Comment: Does it have to be a browser *at all*? By the sound of it, you're not relying on the rendered output - are you relying on javascript to run? Because there are more tools than browsers for just issuing web requests, especially if you're not going to do anything with the results.

Comment: I'm just testing whether the output to be rendered. Initial thoughts are 'yes'

Answer (score 0):

```
start http://domain1.com
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 > nul
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe

start http://domain2.com
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 > nul
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
```

This seems to work quite well for my needs

Comment: If your default web browser is not IE then this code will open firefox,opera, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Start iexplore http://domain1.com
TIMEOUT /T 10
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
```